# 193. on A2Oj always shows Wrong Answer to my submission?

Tags: c++

does anyone know where does this program give wrong output? I tried all the test cases I can think of but it seems that there are some test cases that I don't cover. Here is the link:  http://a2oj.com/p.jsp?ID=193

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int count_Char(string s, char key){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if (s[i] == key){
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int max(int arr[],int size, int &maxi){
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (arr[i]>max){
            max = arr[i];
            maxi = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
int main(){
    char alpha[26] = { 'a', 'b' , 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x','y', 'z' };
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    const int MaxSize = 100;
    const int rows = N;
    string Candies[MaxSize];
    int **countArr = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        countArr[i] = new int[MaxSize];
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cin >> Candies[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MaxSize; j++){
            countArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    int maxCountArr[MaxSize];
    int maxindex[26];
    int maxi = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Candies[i].size();j++){
            if (Candies[i][j] >= 'a' && Candies[i][j] <= 'z'){
                countArr[i][Candies[i][j] - 'a']++;
            }
        }
        maxCountArr[i] = max(countArr[i], MaxSize, maxi);
        maxindex[i] = maxi;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                cout << maxCountArr[i] << ' ' << alpha[maxindex[i]] << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a test case for which your program gives a wrong output:

Input:

```
2
ffff
abc
```

Output:

```
4 f
1 f
```

The reason is that you don't reset `maxi` to 0 et each iteration of the 4th for loop in the `main` function. Just change it to:

```
int maxi;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    maxi = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < Candies[i].size();j++){
        if (Candies[i][j] >= 'a' && Candies[i][j] <= 'z'){
            countArr[i][Candies[i][j] - 'a']++;
        }
    }
    maxCountArr[i] = max(countArr[i], MaxSize, maxi);
    maxindex[i] = maxi;
}
```

## Update

The size of your `maxindex` array is also wrong: it's an array with 26 elements and you write N elements to it, which leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when N>26. Changing its definition to `int maxindex[rows];` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks very much , but it still wont accept my submission looks there is also another test case other than this @DeepBlackDwarf